# Ubuntu 20.04 Instalation - Freeze During Install

Tags: drivers, system-installation, 20.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 beta to my PC.

When I boot from the live-USB and select "Try Linux", the system freezes at some random point of time.

I googled the cause and it seems to be because of Nouveau drivers. I have Nvidia GTX 660 Ti.

People in other questions advice to go to the advanced options when booting and set `nomodeset`. But there is no advanced menu in 20.04 installer.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're helping to test the development release (*focal fossa* isn't 20.04 until release time), then you can also use #ubuntu-quality via IRC or telegram, however general support should still go to #ubuntu+1 sites until *focal fossa* has been released and reached stable 20.04).

Comment: I solved it by booting the live USB as "UEFI Kingston USB" instead of just "Kingston USB". It showed the grub menu with "Try Ubuntu (safe graphics)" and I was able to install it.